# Why does `create-react-app` need `jsconfig.json` for absolute imports, but Webpack does not?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm learning to implement React projects *without* `create-react-app`.

I am using the standard `webpack`/`babel` toolchain to accomplish this. More specifically, `webpack@5.48.0`.

To enable absolute imports in a React project bootstrapped by `create-react-app`, one needs to specify a `baseUrl` in a `jsconfig.json`.

But I have just implemented absolute imports in my React project using `webpack`’s `resolve.modules` field.

Why is it that `create-react-app` requires a `jsconfig.json` to allow for absolute imports, but `webpack` does not?

Comment: Adding your file configs would be more helpful so we can actually help you.  That being said webpack does require tsconfig.json, without it webpack will break with an error on compilation.  The only reason I can imagine why it's not requiring tsconfig is if typescript isn't used at all, only babel is used, if you haven't used ts-loader.

Comment: @Matriarx I’m not using TypeScript in this project, I mentioned the `tsconfig.json` for completeness. Should I remove mention of it?

Comment: Why you saying that CRA requires `*config.json`? `*config.json` are vscode/ts compiler configurations, how its related to webpack?

Comment: In that case create-react-app probably has ts-loader installed in which case it'll need tsconfig, whereas vanilla webpack doesn't need to have ts-loader installed.  If you're only using babel you probably installed babel-loader and without ts-loader you won't need tsonfig.  What's more is that react is probably configured to run typescript through babel, but you haven't done that.

Comment: @DennisVash I think you misunderstood my question. I’ve clarified it. Also, I use WebStorm and still need a `jsconfig.json` to allow for absolute imports in a `create-react-app` project.

Comment: @Matriarx I’ve removed reference to `tsconfig.json`, since my question doesn’t immediately concern TypeScript. I’ve reframed the question (last sentence) to make it more clear what I am asking.

Yes, I am using `babel-loader`.

Comment: You're still referring to the same thing without knowing it, tsconfig or jsconfig is referring to the same thing, baseUrl is a compiler option for typecsript.  Changing that baseUrl, as far as I'm aware, is only for typescript.  I don't know of any other config that uses baseUrl with relative imports other than typescript.  Unless react is using that jsconfig to override webpack config options, but then I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Also when you use baseUrl in a project you'll also have to alias jest/webpack and everything else with the same urls, otherwise typescript will compile it to javascript and then your code will break not being able to find the relative paths.  I don't know how that's possible without typescript because it's typescript's compiler responsible for that.

Comment: @Matriarx So, you’re saying that specifying options within a `jsconfig.json` is actually overriding a `tsconfig.json` that’s utilized by the IDE? It sounds like you’re saying that JavaScript projects use the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: Most IDEs are preconfigured to look for tsconfig and if it finds it to help you with types, I have no idea what your IDE is doing.  As for react's documentation https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/, jsconfig and tsconfig is the same thing, they probably just support jsconfig in case you're not using typescript, either way they're probably still using typescript behind the scenes to compile that stuff.  And no either you have tsconfig or you have jsconfig, they're the same thing is what I said.

Comment: The only reason you'll ever create a tsconfig file is if you're using typescript, jsconfig is only a react thing because they're likely still using typescript internally to compile stuff for you, which you don't need to know about if you're not using typescript.  Along with that using jsconfig should have no effect on your IDE because you're by definition not using typescript.

Comment: @solidstatejake "to allow for absolute imports in a create-react-app project", when saying "allow absolute imports" it has two meanings, allow webpack support for it or allow IDE support for it, your .json files are for the IDE support. So actually, CRA not requires a .json config as you stated in your question

Comment: @DennisVash [Here is the CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component#absolute-imports) for absolute imports. It doesn’t specifically mention webpack, but I believe that is how it’s being accomplished. My references to the jsconfig do not have to do with IDEs. At least, not intentionally.

Comment: You can use absolute imports without the config, did you try it? You will get errors WITHIN YOUR IDE and you won't be able to reference it, but the bundling will still work since Webpack supports it